# how to show that a grid in gridview is selected in windows 8 app

Tags: windows-8

I want to show grid view grid tile selected like an image i have added 
[selected tile http://www.google.co.in/imgres?um=1&sa=N&rlz=1C1CHMO_enIN532IN532&biw=1366&bih=667&hl=en&tbm=isch&tbnid=a7OwOgEUi8RQWM:&imgrefurl=http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/tilelist-selection.html&docid=AzRzczojIstprM&imgurl=http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/media/tileList-selected-tile-appearance.png&w=327&h=170&ei=D4HNUcutJYeFrgeuy4HgDg&zoom=1&ved=1t:3588,r:0,s:0,i:78&iact=rc&page=1&tbnh=136&tbnw=261&start=0&ndsp=17&tx=73&ty=66](http://www.google.co.in/imgres?um=1&sa=N&rlz=1C1CHMO_enIN532IN532&biw=1366&bih=667&hl=en&tbm=isch&tbnid=a7OwOgEUi8RQWM:&imgrefurl=http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/tilelist-selection.html&docid=AzRzczojIstprM&imgurl=http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/media/tileList-selected-tile-appearance.png&w=327&h=170&ei=D4HNUcutJYeFrgeuy4HgDg&zoom=1&ved=1t:3588,r:0,s:0,i:78&iact=rc&page=1&tbnh=136&tbnw=261&start=0&ndsp=17&tx=73&ty=66)

Comment: "http://www.google.co.in/imgres?um=1&sa=N&rlz=1C1CHMO_enIN532IN532&biw=1366&bih=667&hl=en&tbm=isch&tbnid=a7OwOgEUi8RQWM:&imgrefurl=http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/tilelist-selection.html&docid=AzRzczojIstprM&imgurl=http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/media/tileList-selected-tile-appearance.png&w=327&h=170&ei=D4HNUcutJYeFrgeuy4HgDg&zoom=1&ved=1t:3588,r:0,s:0,i:78&iact=rc&page=1&tbnh=136&tbnw=261&start=0&ndsp=17&tx=73&ty=66"

Comment: above is the link of image

Comment: Ok i have resolved the issue my myself by changing the SELECTIONMODE to multiple.

Comment: Actually it's a matter of enabling selection. SelectionMode set to multiple, will allow you to select more then one element in the gridview - I'd say pretty obvious.

Comment: yup i got that but one more question can we change the color or the border that come after we selected the particular item. the border right now coming is blue with white right image.

Comment: yes, you can, you must override some default styles, I'll post you an answer with an useful link.

Comment: thanks for your reply. am waiting for your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a different question for a different issue.
Anyways, if you want to customize the looks of many visual items on the page, you will need to override the default resource brush.

You have a big list [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/957b333f-035f-448e-9f4a-213d1290ee51/indeterminate-progressbar-foreground-dosent-work) (scroll down to the bottom of the post on the page, until you get to the ones with `SolidColorBrush`.

You're using a `GridView` and there's nothing for gridview on that list. I am not sure but I think `ListView` and `GridView` resource brushes are the same.

You can try to see if there are any resources for the GridView, or, style a ListView entirely as a GridView. A `ListView` can be easily changed to look like a GridView like this (I changed the template of the panel in which the items are shown) :

```
<ListView x:name="MyListView"
          SelectionMode="Single">
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapGrid Orientation="Vertical"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
</ListView>
```

Now, for applying those resource brushes from the link, you have to write in the `App.xaml` file, the `ThemeDictionary` (in the interior of the `ResourceDictionary`) :

```
<ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Default">
        <!-- Changed ThemeBrsuh default color for selected item within ListView -->
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemSelectedPointerOverBorderThemeBrush" Color="#A8A8A8" />
         <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="Transparent" />
         <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemSelectedPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="DimGray" />
         <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="#A8A8A8" />
     </ResourceDictionary>
</ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
```

This will override the default colors for all your `ListView`s in your app. You can't have one with a red theme and another with a blue theme. I don't know if it's possible, so far I haven't found any solutions.

Still, I hope this one helps you out in your matter.

Comment: thanks Vasile,I have just added the solid colorbrush in my resource dictionary and it is working in my case.